# ASP .NET MVC: Redirect to a view if certain condition is not met

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, view

I finally got to try .NET MVC this weekend and, as was expected, ran into some hurdles.

I am trying to password-protect my site while it's under development. The basic idea is very very simple: in my BaseController class (that inherits from the Controller and is inherited by all other controller classes) I check whether a certain Session variable is set. If it is not set,  I need to redirect them to a specific view, where users can enter a password. The key is that this check should happen on every request, regardless of what part of the site they're accessing. This is what I tried but has failed:
Override OnActionExecuting in the BaseController class and check for the following:

```
if ((Session["siteAuth"] == null || (bool)Session["siteAuth"] != true) && 
        filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName != "EnterPassword") {
   RedirectToAction("EnterPassword");
}
else {
   base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

OnActionExecuting executes on every request, however, RedirectToAction does not happen. Basically it just renders the view that it would otherwise render.

The closest solution that I found was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766258/asp-net-mvc-redirecting-to-a-controller-action-by-passing-some-data), but mine needs to happen on every request.

Any hints as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why don't you just decorate your action or controller with `[Authorize]`?

Comment: Perhaps because I had no idea such thing existed. Researching it right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You should set filterContext.Result:

```
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction("EnterPassword");
    }
```

but as Daniel Liuzzi said, there are other better ways to do it.

Comment: +1 this may not have been the best answer for the question here, but it was exactly what I needed for something more complex than a simple `Authorize`. Cheers.